# Jmeter: Issues with BeanShellPostProcessor and BeanShellSampler

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

(1)    What is the GUI class equivalent of `BeanShellPostProcessor`? i.e what is xxx below?

```
bspp.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, BeanShellPostProcessor.class.getName());
bspp.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, XXX.class.getName());
```

(2)

```
BeanShellSampler bss = new BeanShellSampler();
bss.setName("Bean Shell Sampler Test");
bss.setScript("log.info(\"*****************A sample Message***********************\");");
bss.setParameters("param1");
bss.setResetInterpreter(true);
```

For the code above in (2) only the name reflects in the `.jmx` file. The script, parameters or the reset checkbox do not reflect. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

GUI class for the Beanshell Post Processor is [org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.BeanShellSamplerGui](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/control/gui/BeanShellSamplerGui.html). You can see Test Element class along with associated GUI class by expanding [log viewer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) (click yellow triangle with exclamation mark at the top right corner) and choosing "Help -> What's this node" from main menu.

[image: What is this node]

As far as I understand, you're trying to create a JMeter test plan programmatically. I would recommend referring https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/ as an example of creating a JMeter test in Java.

Also be informed that it is recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy scripting engine](http://www.groovy-lang.org/integrating.html) so consider switching to it if you're still on early stages of test development and it won't be too much overhead. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for more detailed explanation, Beanshell and Groovy benchmark and scripting best practices.

---

Update: code to properly construct Beanshell Sampler programmatically

```
BeanShellSampler bss = new BeanShellSampler();
bss.setName("Bean Shell Sampler Test");
bss.setProperty(BeanShellSampler.SCRIPT, "log.info(\"*****************A sample Message***********************\");");
bss.setProperty(BeanShellSampler.PARAMETERS,"param1");
bss.setProperty(new BooleanProperty(BeanShellSampler.RESET_INTERPRETER, true));
bss.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, BeanShellSampler.class.getName());
bss.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,BeanShellSamplerGui.class.getName());
```

---

Comment: Thank you Dmitri... Your reply did help quite a bit, but just out of curiosity, could you kindly throw some light on question (2) of the original post. I am able to see the change to the name of the bean shell sampler node [that I change through the code], but not the script line, parameters or the reset checkbox. 

When I create the node through the GUI I am able to see the xml element with the appropriate script contents in the jmx file. But when I view the xml [.jmx] file of the tree that I create programmatically I see the element present but the contents of the element are empty.

Comment: Apologies, provided wrong GUI class name initially. I also updated answer with proper code so programatically created sampler will show up in JMeter GUI.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. That answers the question. I now have the same question for BeanShellPostProcessor, I cant seem to find a script field nor does the setScript work, a pointer on how to identify the api would help a good deal.